# Jquery spawned image does not register onclick

Tags: jquery

Ok so i've run into a problem i simply do not understand how to fix.
The idea is: there's 1 mole image that has an onclick() function that removes the mole that was clicked, and spawns another mole. At the same time, there's a timer that spawns a mole every second. As it is right now it is only the first mole that spawns works and everything else is a dud and does nothing. I've combed the internet for ANY answer for about 2 days now and I've come up with nothing.

code posted for reference.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var pointcount = 0;
var time = 30;

$('#start_button').click(function() 
{

    $("#timer").text(time + " seconds left...");
    $("html").css('background-color', 'white');
    $("#howtoplay").text("");
    $("#start_button").attr("disabled",true);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
    $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;" />');



    $('.mole').click(function() 
        {
            pointcount++;
            $("#score").text(pointcount + " points");
            y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
            x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
            $('.mole').remove();
            $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;" />');
        })




    setInterval(
    function timer(){ 
        time -= 1;      
        $("#timer").text(time + " seconds left...");
        if(time == -1)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(
    function(){ 
        y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
        $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;" />');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem, in fact that really didn't change anything.

Comment: well i don't know all the problems i'm having.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the click event isn't recognized after a new one is spawned in. You need to re-define the event. Something like this.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var pointcount = 0;
var time = 30;

$('#start_button').click(function() 
{

    $("#timer").text(time + " seconds left...");
    $("html").css('background-color', 'white');
    $("#howtoplay").text("");
    $("#start_button").attr("disabled",true);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
    $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' 
   height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;"/>');

    $('.mole').click(function() { MoleClick() } )

    function MoleClick() {
        pointcount++;
        $("#score").text(pointcount + " points");
        y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
        $('.mole').remove();
        $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;" />');
    }

    setInterval(
    function timer(){ 
        time -= 1;      
        $("#timer").text(time + " seconds left...");
        if(time == -1)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
     }, 1000);

    setInterval(
    function(){ 
        y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
        $('html').append('<img class="mole" src="img/mole.png" width='+200+' height='+177+' style="position:absolute; top:'+y+'px; left:'+x+'px;" />');

        $(".mole").unbind()
        $('.mole').click(function() { MoleClick() } )
    }, 1000);
});
```